# MySQL inner join for specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

table `product`:

| product_id | product_name | price | added_on | modified_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Phone | 100 | 2021-09-25 | 2021-09-25 |

table `product_image`:

| id | product_id | product_image1 | added_on | modified_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | phoneimage.jpg | 2021-09-27 | 2021-09-27 |

I am trying to display product image table in a page with inner join but the problem is that I have same name for added_on and modified_on I want to select from table `product` `product_id`, `product_name`, `price` and from table `product_image` all.

So far I have used this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `product_image` 
INNER JOIN `product` ON product_image.product_id = product.product_id 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

product image display:

[image]

Comment: Further to the below correct answers, you can shorten your table name references like so: `SELECT t.added_on, nt.added_on ... FROM table t INNER JOIN new_table nt ON t.ref_id = nt.ref_id WHERE t.added_on > <value>... ` etc. Which can really slim down big queries. So you have `<Table_name> [table] <table shorthand> [t]` in your `FROM` clause and use the shorthand reference in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it with the table name as alias:

```
SELECT product.product_id,
    product.product_name,
    product.price,
    product_image.id,
    product_image.product_id,
    product_image.product_image1,
    product_image.added_on,
    product_image.modified_on
FROM product_image
INNER JOIN product ON product_image.product_id = product.product_id
ORDER BY product_image.id DESC
```

This way you make sure you take the columns from the table you want to.

Answer (score 3):

Don't select all the columns. select columns which you need from any table using `tableName.columnName`

```
SELECT 
product.product_id,
product.product_name,
product.price ,
product_image.added_on,
product_image.modified_on 
FROM product_image 
inner join product 
on product_image.product_id = product.product_id 
ORDER BY id DESC
```